# Сортировка и фильтрация данных / AJAX или чистый JS ?

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Есть простой книжный интернет магазин.

На главной странице есть форма поиска, книг по названию.
Если только пользователь зашел на страницу то никакого запроса на поиск книг не было, и будет выведено последние 10 книг из БД.

Структура вывода книг на сайте примерно такая:

```
<ul>
<li>item 1...<li>
<li>item 2...<li>
...
<li>item N...<li>
</ul>
```

Нужно реализовать сортировку книг по цене, названию ... и фильстрацию по цене и тематике книг.

Вопрос: Каким образом лучше эти функции реализовать, т.е. на сервере через sql запросы и возвращать отсортированные или фильтрованные данные, или тоже самое делать на клиенте, через javascript ?

Какой из методов более оптимальный с точки зрения быстродействия ? Или как бы бы правильнее?

Comment: сортировку и фильтрацию вы будете выполнять на том, что уже отдали пользователю (те 10 книг) или по всему списку доступных? Если по всему списку и фильтровать/сортировать у клиента, то выходит, что вы ему весь список книг сначала отдать должны. И тут проще и быстрее фильтровать/сортировать на стороне сервера, отдавая только то, что ему нужно. Если же можно обойтись без запроса на сервер, то, очевидно, выполнять эти операции будет быстрее в браузере.

Comment: Изначально при запуске сайта, последние 10 книг - для демонстрации. 

На них тоже должна работать сортировки и фильтрация.

Потом если пользователь в поисковом запросе введет "turbo pascal" то ему выдаст все книги где встречается эта подстрока, и в результате пользователь захочет отсортировать все книги которые он получил на запрос книги по цене, и то же самое с остальными.